# MVC client side validation with subproperties

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3

Having the following classes:

```
public class MyObjB {
     [Required(ErrorMessage = "I need it")]
     public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class MyObjA {
     [Required(ErrorMessage = "I need it")]
     public string Name { get; set; }

     public MyObjB MyObjB { get; set; }
}
```

The View: using the model as MyObjA

```
@{ Html.EnableClientValidation(); }
@{Html.BeginForm();}
@Html.ValidationSummary("Some errors") @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    // MyObjA part
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name):
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name) 
    @Html.ValidationMessage("Name", "*")

    // MyObjB part
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MyObjB.Name):
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.MyObjB.Name) 
    @Html.ValidationMessage("MyObjB.Name", "*")
@{ Html.EndForm(); }
```

The EnableClientValidation will not work....
I think this is related with the "." (dot) used and problems with the javacript, but I can be wrong and the cause be different.

If I do the same form but only for the MyObjB, it will work fine and the ClientValidation is done correctly.

How do you people use EnableClientValidation with subproperties?

Thank you.

**EDIT 1 - For byte request**

View:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.MyObjB.Name)
```

HTML Result:

```
<input id="MyObjB_Name" name="MyObjB.Name" type="text" value="" />
```

Comment: Could you post the html ID generated by @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.MyObjB.Name)  ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

what you need to do is create a viewmodel for your view
which will have properties of Class A and Class B

```
public class ViewModelAB
{
    [validation error message]  
    A PropertyA { get; set; }

    [validation error message]  
    B PropertyB { get; set;}
}
```

and use            this viewmodel model strogly types to your view

Comment: Yes, I know that I could solve this by transforming the 2 classes in only 1, then the validation would work fine. But that is not the point of my question.

Comment: Ok. could you post CDATA in your view. it wil be something as //<![CDATA[ at end of the view when you open it in notepad.  this CDATA shows the ValidationRules and rendered messages for your properties. Should be something simillar as below.....

Comment: if (!window.mvcClientValidationMetadata) { window.mvcClientValidationMetadata = []; }
window.mvcClientValidationMetadata.push({"Fields":[{"FieldName":"Name","ReplaceValidationMessageContents":true,"ValidationMessageId":"Name_validationMessage","ValidationRules":[{"ErrorMessage":"I need it .","ValidationParameters":{},"ValidationType":"required"}]}

Answer (score 0):

I think you must use following in you web.config:

```
     <appSettings>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
</appSettings>
```

Comment: Hazro thanks for the contribution. With or without those appSettings (I tried your tip) the validation is working with a "normal" model. It just doens't work when the model has "complex" sub properties. And this is my problem :(

Answer (score 0):

It will work as long as you have the reference and initialization of objB in objA, because your model to the view is ObjA